# object not showing in browser

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a c# control class inside of a dll, then this control is embedded in a web page in an asp.net application by using the object tag. When the dll is compiled with .net  3.5 sp1 and the web application also runs in .net 3.5 sp1, the code works fine. But when the dll is compiled in .net 4.0 and the web application runs in 4.0, the control does not show up in the web page. All I see is a box with an object icon in the upper left corner. I'm suspecting that the problem is security related. Any ideas?

Comment: object tag? can you not just embed it normally? ie <yournamespace:yourcontrol id="foo" runat="server">

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the answer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/e293ed8e-be48-4c4a-838b-dcf3c2cec5b7

Thanks!